# check box validation before clicking proceed button

Tags: javascript, validation, checkbox

```
<a href="page.html" > <button type="button" id="proceed-button">Proceed </button></a>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="yes">
By checking the box, I certify that have read the above disclaimers and agree to the rules. </input>
```

I have a checkbox and a button which will take me to next page. But, before I press the button the check box has to be ticked. If not, a label has to be displayed below the check box saying "accept to rules first". Help? Also, it would be great if i can highlight the checkbox to red if i click proceed without checking the checkbox. Can use javascript/jquery.

Comment: Where is your JavaScript function to do this. Have you researched this before asking a question here?

Comment: I'm asking for the javascript to do this.

Comment: Can YOu Use jQuery ?

Comment: _I'm asking for the javascript to do this_ - SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: check it : document.myform.box1.checked == true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it works

```html
<form action="page.html">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="yes" required>
By checking the box, I certify that have read the above disclaimers and agree to the rules. </input>
<input type="submit" name ="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

To get you started:

```
<input id="checkboxAgree" type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="yes">
```

```js
function checkAgree() 
{
   if (document.getElementbyId("checkboxAgree").getAttribute("checked") )//checkbox is checked
   {
       location.href = "page.html"; //load the next page.
   }
   else
   {
       Alert("You need to check the box before you can continue");
   }

}

document.getElementById("proceed-button").addEventListener("click", checkAgree ,false);
```

`addEventListener` add an `onclick` event to the `button`. When clicked this executes the function `checkAgree`. When the checkbox has the attribute `checked` it is checked and the `if`will render true. `location.href` will load `page.html`.

Please delete the `a` that surrounds your button.